# Windows VB.NET Application exe run as administrator

Tags: vb.net, windows, exe, uac

I created an application that is installed from the setup file which installs all the files required by the program. When I update the application, I can only share the exe files of the update application to the user and not the entire installation package/setup file(not possible due to constraints)(*Reason: so that he can run the application with out me having to make a new installation package/setup file  and user having to install from the setup file*) I am unsuccessful in my attempts so far. Can any one suggest if this is possible or if I am doing something wrong?

P.S : I have added the manifest file with privilege of always working as an administrator with out which I am unable to run my base application ( *Error : Access to the path c:/xxxx/Tnsnames.ora* denied)

Comment: Is there a valid reason your base application is unable to run without administrative privileges? Normal applications should always run in non-elevated mode and preferably only use elevation for specific tasks. Having to run an entire application elevated is something that should only be done by very specific applications. If it's just because else the app won't run, then you need to configure your installer properly, to set the right permissions on your install directly, and/or move shared data to the default shared application data folder.

Comment: The tnsnames.ora file has encrypted values of the connection string which is decrypted in the code... and this is the reason why the entire application is run with administrative privileges. The tnsnames.ora  is in the default shared application folder. Should I change this ?]

Comment: If I understand, your .exe changes the .ora everytime it is run? I've only seen people storing the connection string in the .config file, and store the server information in the .ora file.

Comment: A setup program already runs with admin privileges so that doesn't get you anywhere.  You cannot open a file that is locked.  Like the database that the installer uses.  Use the [documented MSI api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: @the_lotus not exactly, my application checks for the connection string in the tnsnames.ora file which has multiple address' list which enables me to connect to different environments by changing the SID. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm). We have this provision made so that it will be easy for us to log into the environment we want by just changing the tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: @kvrs so your application changes the tnsnames.ora everytime it runs? I still find that strange.

Answer (score 2):

> Manifest file is the answer.
>
> Manifest file is a file in VB project which contains the information
>   about the contents of file distribution. It may contain checksum or
>   hash to verify that file is original and isn't modified in any way.
>   Modifying a file will change its checksum value.

You need to replace `asInvoker` with `requireAdministrator` or `highestAvailable`

Updated link:
Full [tutorial](http://www.downloadinformer.com/how-to-make-a-vb-net-application-always-run-in-administrator-mode/)

Comment: I already added the manifest file and it is the reason why the application runs as administrator when ever it is invoked. I mentioned this in the question but guess i wasn't clear enough..

Comment: The link to article has been changed and this is new one: http://www.downloadinformer.com/how-to-make-a-vb-net-application-always-run-in-administrator-mode/